# Error en una consulta SQL que rompe la página

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Alguien puede mirar esta consulta a ver si se ve algún fallo? Llevo desde ayer y no veo nada, pero la página se rompe.

```
<?php
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ans.id,ans.strnombre panel, ans.strprecio precio_panel, ans.card card, ans.tiempoP, ans.sangreorina, pb.analisis
      FROM analisis ans INNER JOIN pruebas pb ON ans.id = pb.idperfiles
      WHERE ans.tipoprueba IN (1,2,3)
      AND ans.categoria IN (".$_GET['ID'].")
      AND ans.sexo IN (3,".$_GET['GENERO'].")
      GROUP BY ans.id ");

    while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
      $id= $row['id'];

  ?>
```

Comment: Qué error se te muestra? a veces pasa que al crear la cadena del query no dejas un espacio entre por ejemplo pb.idperfiles y la palabra where quedando pb.idperfilesWHERE en éste caso.

Comment: No se como hacer para que me muestre el error, si quito `GROUP BY ans.id ` muestra datos pero mal @zerocool

Comment: ¿Qué tengo dicho de la concatenación de cadenas al SQL? u_u" Además, tal y como tienes el código le falta el `}` final del `while`.

Comment: ¿Has conseguido arreglar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

Verifica la conexión, almacena la consulta en una variable para verificar si es la correcta, o si devuelve algún dato incorrecto. Posiblemente no te está mostrando el script como quieres. Suerte.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_bd");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
/* verificar el SQL */
    $sql = "SELECT ans.id,ans.strnombre panel, ans.strprecio precio_panel, ans.card card, ans.tiempoP, ans.sangreorina, pb.analisis
      FROM analisis ans INNER JOIN pruebas pb ON ans.id = pb.idperfiles
      WHERE ans.tipoprueba IN (1,2,3)
      AND ans.categoria IN (".$_GET['ID'].")
      AND ans.sexo IN (3,".$_GET['GENERO'].")
      GROUP BY ans.id ";
    var_dump($sql);
/* verificar el resultado */
    $results = $mysqli->query($link, $sql);
    var_dump($results);
/* verificar los datos */
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    var_dump($data);
    exit();
```

Comment: No deberías mezclar la interfaz orientada a objetos (`$mysqli->taltal()`) con la de procedimientos (`mysqli_taltal()`).

Answer (score 0):

Tu código podría estar fallando dependiendo de los valores contenidos en `$_GET['ID']` y `$_GET['GENERO']` además de sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) debido a la forma en la que concatenas el contenido de una variable al código SQL.

Si tu consulta SQL falla devuelve `false`, y cuando usas `$results->fetch_array()` puede generar un error que se escribe silenciosamente en el log de error de tu servidor web, mostrando al usuario una página en blanco.

Te recomiendo corregir tu código siguiendo las siguientes recomendaciones:

- Deberías comprobar la validez de los campos de entrada (`$_GET['ID']` y `$_GET['GENERO']`) usando, por ejemplo, la función [`filter_input()`](https://php.net/es/function.filter-input).
- La consulta debe corregirse para escapar correctamente los valores mediante el uso de [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string) o consultas preparadas con [`mysqli::prepare()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.prepare).
- Debes comprobar siempre el resultado de la ejecución de la consulta para mostrar el mensaje de error o bien no continuar con la ejecución del código en caso de no tener datos de registros. por norma general una consulta fallida devuelve `false` y llamar al método `$results->fetch_array()` de `false` o usarlo como parámetro en `mysqli_fetch_array()` da error.
- Debes cerrar correctamente el grupo `while() { ... }`.

Tu código corregido podría ser:

```
<?php
/* Si es necesario, deberíamos hacer verificación de parámetros antes de la consulta SQL */
if (empty($_GET['ID']) === true
  || filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false)
) {
  die('El parámetro "ID" es obligatorio y debe ser un número entero');
}
if (empty($_GET['GENERO']) === true) {
  die('El parámetro "GENERO" es obligatorio');
}
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$results = $mysqli->query("
  SELECT
    ans.id,
    ans.strnombre panel,
    ans.strprecio precio_panel,
    ans.card card, ans.tiempoP,
    ans.sangreorina,
    pb.analisis
  FROM analisis ans
  INNER JOIN pruebas pb
    ON ans.id = pb.idperfiles
  WHERE
    ans.tipoprueba IN (1,2,3)
    AND ans.categoria IN ('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['ID']) ."')
      AND ans.sexo IN (3,'". $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['GENERO']) ."')
  GROUP BY ans.id
");

/* Comprobamos si hubo un error en la consulta SQL */
if ($results === false) {
  die('Error SQL: '. htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}

while ($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
  /* No te recomiendo usar variables intermedias */
  $id = $row['id'];
  /* ... */
}
/* No es necesario, ni recomendable, cerrar PHP si sólo hay código en el script */
```